# Erro no JavaScript ao Chekar asp:CheckBox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, checkbox, onclick

Bom dia. Tenho o seguinte código:

HTML:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckPergunta" runat="server" onchange='SelectChoices(this);' />
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SelectChoices();
    function SelectChoices() {
        var opc = document.getElementById('<%=ckPergunta.ClientID%>').checked;
        if (opc == false) {
            document.getElementById('<%=dlTipoResposta.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('<%=txtRes.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%=dlTipoResposta.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('<%=txtRes.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Acontece que quando eu faço check, na checkBox o código JavaScript não corre. Ou seja não acontece nada. Mas se eu colocar um onChange num asp:TextBox o código JavaScrip funciona direito. O que há de errado?

Comment: Tu no teu `onchange` da `checkbox` estás a enviar (tentar) o elemento para a função, quando ela não tem nenhum parâmetro de entrada. Mesmo se quiseres enviar o elemento, no teu caso a `checkbox`, tens de usar `$(this)`, e não apenas `this`. Agora tens de ver o que realmente queres para te podermos ajudar... Se apagares o `this` do teu `onchange` já funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você está tentando chamar uma função antes dela ser instanciada, com isto o Script dispara uma exceção e a Função nunca é criada, então à seguinte alteração já deve resolver:

```
function SelectChoices() {
    var opc = document.getElementById('<%=ckPergunta.ClientID%>').checked;
    if (opc == false) {
        document.getElementById('<%=dlTipoResposta.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('<%=txtRes.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('<%=dlTipoResposta.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('<%=txtRes.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
    }
}
SelectChoices();
```

Em todo caso, aconselho que faça algumas mudanças no código (apenas para melhorar um pouco o desempenho e ajudar na organização do mesmo), primeiro remova qual quer declaração de scripts inline no HTML, e depois evite fazer consultas aos Elementos DOM, por fim tente não usar styles inline, utilize classes para isto.

**JavaScript**

```
var ckPergunta = document.getElementById('<%= ckPergunta.ClientID%>');
var dlTipoResposta = document.getElementById('<%= dlTipoResposta.ClientID%>');
var txtRes = document.getElementById('<%= txtRes.ClientID%>');

var SelectChoices = function (event) {
  if (ckPergunta.checked) {
    dlTipoResposta.classList.add("invisivel");
    txtRes.classList.add("invisivel");
  } else {
    dlTipoResposta.classList.remove("invisivel");
    txtRes.classList.remove("invisivel");
  }
}

ckPergunta.addEventListener("change", SelectChoices );
```

**CSS**

```
.invisivel {
  display: none
}
```